# Android video stream mms and m3u8

Tags: android, streaming, mms, m3u8

I am trying to play some video streams from mms and m3u8 inside my Android application. It seems that the MediaPlayer doesn't have support on this and from what I have read on FFMPEG it seems there isn't any easy way with that also. I am using Android 2.1 SDK.
Any ideas on what I should in order to make this work? There are some apps there in the store that already do this, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try the Vitamio library, http://vitamio.org

> Vitamio is a multimedia framework for all Android devices. Vitamio works like the Android's default MediaPlayer except that it includes much more powerful features. And it's absolutely free !

The following network protocols are supported for audio and video playback:

```
MMS
RTSP (RTP, SDP)
HTTP progressive streaming
HTTP live streaming (M3U8), for Android 2.1+
```

Comment: What about other library? As Vitamio seems to have some bugs with some certain streams and it's not working exactly as wished.

Comment: Hi i have small problem on play m3u8 video in android.I follows the your answer and finally it is not working properly.I want to play the m3u8 video from http link.Can you tell me please

Comment: @ABitNo Hi I tried your answer but no use.In my application it is not working properly.Please tell me what i did wrong.

Comment: Same question for me, http media files is not working properly.

Comment: Vitamio seems cannot play live streaming and auto update reading m3u8 file.