# Can iPhone stream MMS, RTSP (RTP, SDP), HTTP progressive streaming ,HTTP live streaming (M3U8) files

Tags: iphone, ios, live-streaming, m3u8

I am checking one question in SO, which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063898/android-video-stream-mms-and-m3u8/7064869#7064869), and I thought a question can iPhone also play this files or it will only support `M3U8` for live streaming.

Comment: Please make your suggested edits more substantial.

Comment: @0x7fffffff okey i will....

Comment: http live streaming is supported natively , mms , rtsp/rtp can be played using third party libraries, there is no native support.

Comment: @MichelleCannon thanx for your reply. I have checked `ffmpeg` and `live55` library can you suggest any other library. then it will be useful for future user.who visit this question.

Comment: I think you already know about our framework , www.streammore.tv, live 555 I find is really good in terms of there server, but not so good in terms of their client. Still it is useable.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend checking out the RadioTunes SDK. You may have a one time payment, but it's a great streaming solution library you can drop into your application. I used it for one of my previous clients who wanted to create a Radio Streaming app and he was very satistifed

http://yakamozlabs.com/products/radiotunes